# Is it possible to use imaginary guesses with secant method?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I was playing with Wolfram Alpha today, and noticed that while I could use, say, $2i$ as a guess to solve $e^x+2=0$ with the help of Newton's method, I couldn't do the same with the secant method. Is it possible to use two imaginary guesses with the secant method, even outside of Wolfram Alpha, or does it work only with Newton's method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secant method is the same as Newton method with a finite difference approximation. It works with complex numbers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting me know! Seems like it's just a limitation of Wolfram Alpha then.